# Drop down widget with adding choices in admin page

Tags: python, django, django-models

i want to create a Drop-Down Widget with choices which can be added in the admin page. I was thinking of creating a model for the choices and registering these in the admin webpage and implementing this model into a Form but i can´t seem to grasp on how to go about solving this.
Is my way of thinking in creating a model and implementing it in a Form / ModelForm the right way or is there a easier/better way ?

Comment: So the users don't see the dropdown? The dropdown can only be accessed from the admin page?

Comment: no, the users see the dropdown menu, but the choices can be changed in the admin page.

Comment: You want to add new choices exactly in dropdown(like you click on dropdown and there is a button "add new choice"? Or add them somewhere else(for example in your choice modeladmin) and then they are appear in your dropdown?

Comment: sorry for a confusing question, but i found a solution now which i posted below, maybe that will clear out the confusion on what my goal was.

Answer (score -1):

I got a solution by creating a model and a form:

```
#in the model.py file:
from django.db import models
class A(models.Model):
    asd = models.CharField(max_length=50,default="DEFAULT VALUE")
    def __str__(self):
        return(self.asd)

#in the forms file:
from .models import A
from django import forms
class B(forms.Form):
    a = A.objects.all()
    dropdownwidget = ModelChoiceField(queryset=a,empty_label="-----")
```

now in the admin page i can add to the model and these will be shown as choices in the drop down widget